# Show iframe or div inside video tag after video end

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have video tag :

```
<video id="test" autobuffer style="width:100%;" onClick="this.play(); controls>
        <source src="some file" type="video/mp4">

    </video>
```

And some Javascript :

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    var video = document.getElementsByTagName('test')[0];
        video.onended = function(e) {
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML= '<iframe src="http://www.example.com/myframe" width="100" height="100"></iframe>';
        };
</script>
```

Idea is ,when video end (video.onended) just show iframe or div in video tag. Something like advertisment info..

I try,but no succes..

Tnx,

Comment: Is it a requirement to show it in the video tag? Why can't you replace the video element with your custom ad?

Comment: No,not must, but would like to stay on that place,or above video tag...

Comment: You should go with some css and javascript (hide/show) logic because I don't think you can manipulate the video element in that way

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the whole video element rather than try and replace a child within it. So use `parentNode` to get the video elements parent

`document.getElementById('test').parentNode.innerHTML= '<iframe src="http://www.example.com/myframe" width="100" height="100"></iframe>';`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do like this : [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pZbkX/1641/)

```
<div id="test">  
    <video id="v" controls>
        <source id='mp4' src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    </video>
    <iframe id="overlay" src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

and add some style

```
#test {
    position: relative;
}

#overlay {
    position: absolute;
    ... 
}
```

You just have to add JavaScript code to hide when the video ends, and it will make the job I think ^^